# Accessing nested items through reflection

Tags: reflection, f#

Given the following F# code

```
namespace NS

type A() =
    let agent = MailboxProcessor.Start(fun mbx ->
        let mutable field: int = 0
        
        let f1() = 5

        let rec loop () = async {
            try 
                match! mbx.Receive() with
                | _ ->
                    let f2() = 6
                    ()
            with | _ -> ()
            
            return! loop() }

        loop ())

module B = 
    let a = A()
```

how to reach 'field', 'f1' and 'f2' through reflection starting from 'a' (or typeof<A>)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the code is in a console project, ILSpy reveals how the functions are compiled

[image]

The code is a simplified version of the real one. With the following code (adapted), we can reach the class corresponding to f1 (others are similar).

```
let types = typeof<A>.Assembly.GetTypes()
let f1 = types |> Array.find (fun t -> t.Name.StartsWith("f1") && t.BaseType.Equals(typeof<unit -> int>))
```

I agree with Tomas's observations in principle.

However, in this specific case, being able to do this allowed me to mock the elements and write tests.

I would beg the readers to refrain from entering into the debate on how tests should only be based on interfaces and the like.

I am convinced that we should be able to test any kind of code without changing a single comma, and against the view that we need to write code to be "testable". Test code should adapt to code under test, not viceversa

Answer (score 2):

The names `field`, `f1` and `f2` refer to local variables of functions - `field` and `f1` are locals of the function passed to the agent and `f2` is a local of the async workflow (which is compiled as a function).

Their values will end up being stored somewhere in an object that represents a closure (keeping values of the locals associated with the function). You would, in principle, be able to reach those via reflection starting from `a` (after all, the GC can reach them!) but it would involve following a chain of private fields with mangled names that are not intended to be accessed.

In other words, this is probably not something that can reasonably be done. It is a better idea to expose the values directly as members of the class `A`, if you want to access them:

```
type A() =
  let mutable field: int = 0
  let f1() = 5
  let f2() = 6

  let agent = MailboxProcessor.Start(fun mbx ->
    let rec loop () = async {
      try 
          match! mbx.Receive() with
          | _ ->
              ()
      with | _ -> ()
      return! loop() }
    loop ())

  member x.Field = field
  member x.F1 = f1 ()
  member x.F2 = f2 ()
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your code snippet doesn't actually use the values of `field`, `f1`, or `f2`, the compiler will eliminate them. Thus, they don't exist at runtime, and aren't available to reflection. See decompiled code [here](https://sharplab.io/#v2:DYLgZgzgNAJiDUAfAdgQwLYFMIAdUGNMACAOQGUBYAKGoBcBPHYgQQAoBKIgXmqL6OCZaRVAHNMyYVyIBZVAEtgAIwD2ADwAKAJxWEIEFVoB0ZWqi21WYAK7Ii6JWqIBaAHy9+nwcPTWzSwSIweUxgOCJ5SW4iAAYPTz54hO8ggEYOaIBWaiSvISItTHwBFRUcIgzpVAh6ZGKAb1yEvloteiIm5s90VFp8AAsAQntHIwAlIsx5ADdMDIB3eVp+zq6+RCIAfRd3KjX9/hSwACZKogA2VYO+Div+ReWiDe23CvY7xL3rwtprLWRhsBSjgMgBfHJfZpAspvd40KjoFQwayBABC0SSKVQ0TY7CAA).

Presumably, this code snippet is a simplified version of a more complex program that does use the values, in which case Tomas is correct that finding them via reflection at runtime is theoretically possible, but futile in practice. The actual names involved are implementation details of the compiler that can't reasonably be relied upon.

Comment: Would marking type declaration as ReflectedDefinition help here to get internals with quotation?